# Translating Java to Lua

Tags: java, lua

I am making a game and I am having trouble translating the following Java codes to Lua:

```
pat = new ArrayList<Integer>();

random = new Random();
```

How would I go about this in Lua?
I have tried the following:

```
pat = {}

random = math.random()
```

Is this correct?
My start function looks like this

```
function start()
    local pat = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    local random = math.random(1,4)
    local patternIndex = 0
    local light = 2
    local clicked = 0
    local pattern = true
end
```

Is this a bad way to start it? Any Advice?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The real problem arises when you use these things.

Comment: I am trying to create a game of simon says. and i want to create an array when the game starts, along with a number randomizer.

Comment: `local` variables are visible only inside your function

Answer (score 0):

> Is this correct?

Not quite.

> Random random = new Random();

Creates a new random number *generator*. You would then call methods like `nextInt(int n)` or `nextDouble()` to actually *generate* a random number.

In Lua, there is one global random number generator. Calling `math.random` does not create a generator, it uses that global generator to generate a number.

---

> pat = {}

This creates a table, which can be used as a list of doubles. If you need them to behave like ints, and you're not using Lua 5.3+, you'll need to be careful to do truncation of fractional portions yourself (e.g. `math.floor`)